# Mask part of field on form I can't control

Tags: javascript, masking

I have a form that I can't control, but I can add CSS and JS to the page it is on. This form in particular contains a social field. The form doesn't hide the social. I've thought about just simply changing the input type from text to password, but there has been the request to show the last 4 or even show the character on input but mask after.

I've got code that can mask however I want, but if it's all done via JS it technically breaks the form input as it changes it from values to `*` or what not. How can I preseve the value but at the same time mask it. I started down the path of appending to it and such but the input eventually becomes corrupted with `*` values.

The below code has the visual functionality that I want, but now I need to somehow preserve the value of the field. What I did was create a secondary field with the goal of showing the mask while putting the real value behind the scenes into the field that will actually be used.

```
var social = document.querySelector('#ctl00_mainContent_ApplicationForm_ApplicationForm_ApplicationFormControl_datatel_ssn_datatel_ssn');
            var socialVal = social.value;
            if(social !== null){
                var newSocial = document.createElement('input');
                newSocial.type = "text";
                newSocial.maxLength = 11;
                newSocial.value = social.value;
                social.parentNode.insertBefore(newSocial, social.nextSibling);
                //social.style.display = 'none';
                newSocial.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
                    var newVal = newSocial.value.replace(/-/gi,'');
                    var maskVal = newVal;
                    social.value = maskVal;
                    if(maskVal.length < 6){
                        maskVal = maskVal.replace(/\d/g,'*');
                    }
                    newSocial.value = maskVal;
                },false);
            }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't storing the "old" value in a javascript variable work?

Comment: No, must be vanilla JS. If you can write a solution in jQuery I can convert it though. @Gerdinand I'm not sure what you mean? If I store it in a variable and people type how would I update it. What would I update it against. I need it to update as people type. Can you show me what you are thinking.

Comment: Still looking for an answer, but I went this route: https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Toggle-Password-Security-Form-Input-Characters-Tutorial and just used JS to make the social password by default.